# Django/PIL: AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm testing example code validate image field ([Django custom validation in model form for imagefield (max file size etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129677/django-custom-validation-in-model-form-for-imagefield-max-file-size-etc)):

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField

class Event(models.Model):

   # (...)
    banner = FilerImageField(verbose_name='Banner')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from PIL import Image
from .models import Event


class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_banner(self):
        image = self.cleaned_data.get('banner', False)
        if image:
            img = Image.open(image)
            img.load()
            width, height = img.size

            max_width = 879
            max_height = 392

            if width > max_width or width < max_width or height > max_height or height < max_height: 
                raise forms.ValidationError('Imagem está com dimensão incorreta: %s x %s pixels. Insira uma imagem com %s x %s pixels.' 
                                            %(width, height, max_width, max_height))
            # Máx 3MB
            if len(image) > (3 * 1024 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Arquivo de imagem muito grande (máximo 3MB).')

            name_type, ext = image.content_type.split('/')
            if not (name_type == 'image' and ext.lower() in ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg']):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Por favor, use imagem em formato JPG, JPEG ou PNG.')
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Não foi possível ler a imagem carregada.')
        return image
```

error when registering image not django-admin. Version: Pillow==4.3.0, Python==3.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2534, in open
    fp.seek(0)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 551, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 224, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1508, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1408, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1440, in _changeform_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 183, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 384, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 405, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\integrafundaj\events\admin.py", line 19, in clean_banner
    img = Image.open(image)
  File "C:\Users\Lidy Monteiro\Developer\integra-fundaj\.myvenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2536, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I tried `img = Image.open(image, mode='r')` in function clean_banne, but it does not work. how to solve? the problem is in the python version?

Answer (score -1):

According to [Pillow documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/installation.html#notes) Python 3.6 is not yet supported. Please try another version of python.